# Cannot Parse Multiline with Regular Expressions

Tags: php

```
<trans-unit id="8">
<source>Special settings for:</source>
<target>Special settings for:</target>
</trans-unit>
```

I am trying to get the ID and the contents of the target tag. The above structure is repeated many times in the XML I am trying to parse.

I am currently using the expression below, but it doesn't return anything but empty arrays:

```
preg_match_all('#<trans-unit id="(.*)">(.*)<target>(.*)</target>(.*)</trans-unit>#Ui', $xml, $matches);
```

Comment: You might also have wrong regular expression, try putting the tags on one line (just to test it) and see if the regex will work. If not you may have some other errors. for example i think that you should use stuff like `<\/target>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the /s pattern modifier to make the dot (.*) match all characters including newline characters. By default PCRE treats the string as a long one-line one.

http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

So in the above example:

```
preg_match_all('#<trans-unit id="(.*)">(.*)<target>(.*)</target>(.*)</trans-unit>#Uis', $xml, $matches);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an xml parser instead.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
print_r($xml);
```

Comment: For some weird reason, this returned False in my test.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `s` option to your regular expression in PHP to add the multiline match capabilities (i.e. `.` will match newlines too).

**edit**: Changed the `m` option to `s` for further references, see the comment below.

Comment: Again that confusion. ) It's `/s` option that makes `.` match "\n"; and `/m` option changes how `^` and `$` are processed. )

Comment: Indeed. I used to use the two in conjuction, hence the confusion.